# Interpolation search?

Tags: c++, algorithm, std

I have a uniform 1D grid with value `{0.1, 0.22, 0.35, 0.5, 0.78, 0.92}`. These values are equally positioned from position 0 to 5 like following:

```
value       0.1      0.22      0.35       0.5      0.78      0.92
             |_________|_________|_________|_________|_________|
    
position     0         1         2         3         4         5
```

Now I like to extract/interpolated value positioned, say, at `2.3`, which should be

```
val(2.3) = val(2)*(3-2.3) + val(3)*(2.3-2)
         = 0.35*0.7 + 0.5*0.3
         = 0.3950
```

So how should I do it in a optimized way in C++? I am on Visual Studio 2017.

I can think of a binary search, but is any some std methods/or better way to do the job? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have one array of float {0.1, 0.22, ..., 0.92}? Or do you have value pairs, [(0, 0.1), (1, 0.22), ..., (5, 0.92)]?

Comment: _"I can think of a binary search"_ it's not clear to me how any type of "search" is happening here.  You are using the example `2.3` to mean "interpolate between val(2) and val(3)", right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the integer part of the interpolation value and use that to index the two values you need to interpolate between. No need to use binary search as you are always know between which two values you interpolate. Only need to look out for indices that are outside of the values if that could ever happen.

**This only works if the values are always mapped to integer indices starting with zero.**

```
#include <cmath>

float get( const std::vector<float>& val, float p )
{
  // let's assume p is always valid so it is good as index
  const int a = static_cast<int>(p); // round down
  const float t = p - a;
  return std::lerp(val[a], val[a+1], t); 
}
```

**Edit:**

std::lerp is a c++20 feature. If you use earlier versions you can use the following implementation which should be good enough:

```
float lerp(float a, float b, float t)
{
   return a + (b - a) * t;
}
```

Comment: One might also make sure `a >= 0` and `b < length_of_val` and extrapolate from the proper edge segment if not.

Comment: You shouldn't pass that vector by value. Use a const reference to avoid making an unnecessary copy.

Comment: I got error message 'lerp': is not a member of 'std'   :( I am on Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: I wrote an answer only to realize you already said the same thing. +1, this is a good solution (and kudos for using `std::lerp`)

Comment: @NickXTsui You need to include <cmath>. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/lerp